Is a normal domain a filtered colimit of Noetherian normal domains?
As described in the title, is any normal domain a filtered colimit of Noetherian normal domains? It will be great if one can show this, even with additional conditions, or if one can provide a counterexample.

Every commutative unital ring is the filtered colimit of its unital subrings that are finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$.  By the Noether normalization theorem, the normalization of each such subring is finite over the subring, hence itself finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$.
